# d3 append() with function argument

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This works:

```
// A
d3.select("body").selectAll(".testDiv")
  .data(["div1", "div2", "div3"])
  .enter().append("div")
    .classed("testDiv", true)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

The following snippet is identical except that the argument for append, instead of
being "div" as above, is a function(d) that simply returns "div":

```
// B
d3.select("body").selectAll(".testDiv")
  .data(["div1", "div2", "div3"])
  .enter().append(function(d) { return "div"; })
    .classed("testDiv", true)
   .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

B, however, does not work, and instead returns the error message 
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not
of type 'Node'."

How is "div" as an argument for append() different from `function(d) { return "div"; }`?

Answer (score 15):

The short answer is if you are giving `append` a function as an argument the function must return a DOM element. The documentation of the append method states:

> The name may be specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append.

The following is a valid use of append with a function as an argument:

```
.append(function() { return document.createElement('div');});
```

As the code below does not return a DOM element it would be considered invalid.

```
.append(function() { return 'div';});
```

The reason for this may be seen in the source code:

```
  d3_selectionPrototype.append = function(name) {
    name = d3_selection_creator(name);
    return this.select(function() {
      return this.appendChild(name.apply(this, arguments));
    });
  };

  function d3_selection_creator(name) {
    function create() {
      var document = this.ownerDocument, namespace = this.namespaceURI;
      return namespace ? document.createElementNS(namespace, name) : document.createElement(name);
    }
    function createNS() {
      return this.ownerDocument.createElementNS(name.space, name.local);
    }
    return typeof name === "function" ? name : (name = d3.ns.qualify(name)).local ? createNS : create;
  }
```

As you can see if `typeof name === "function"` (near the bottom) is true the `create` or `createNS` functions are never called. As `appendChild` only accepts a DOM element the function given to append must be a DOM element.

Comment: a D3.js alternative to document.createElement("div") is d3.creator("div").  This will return an html element for use in .append().

Answer (score 3):

If the purpose for adding a function within the `.append()` is to have a conditional statement, then you have to make sure to have a return for every case.

You can't choose to append a `div` only sometimes. A DOM element has to always be returned otherwise you will get the same error.

For example this will fail:

```
.append(function(d) { 
  if(sometimesTrue) {
    return document.createElement('div');
  }
});
```

An `else {}` is **required** to return some other DOM element for the `.append()` to work properly.

This is something I saw with D3.v3 so not sure if handled better in newer versions. Hope that helps someone.