# Compose SVG with d3 from DOM elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to display possible outcomes of throwing two dice using D3.js and therefore repeatedly need the same die faces. So I wanted to turn those into components.

My approach was this:

```js
function dieFace(d){
  const elt = d3.create("rect")
    .attr("x", 10 + 200 * d[0])
    .attr("y", 10 + 120 * d[1])
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("rx", 24)
    .attr("ry", 24)
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", "5")

  return elt.node()

}
```

and then use this component like this (also cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485046/d3-append-with-function-argument)):

```js
{
  const width = 200;
  const height = 200;
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;");
  
  svg.data([[0,0]]).append(dieFace)

  return svg.node()
}
```

unfortunately, the above does not display anything. But using `F12` the svg does actually contain the `rect` component

[image]

what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [ReadMe for d3](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/README.md#namespace) you need to specify the correct namespace if you're not creating HTML elements. Fortunately d3 makes this really easy

> d3.create(name) · Source
>
> Given the specified element name, returns a single-element selection containing a detached element of the given name in the current document. This method assumes the HTML namespace, so you must specify a namespace explicitly when creating SVG or other non-HTML elements; see namespace for details on supported namespace prefixes.
>
> d3.create("svg:g") // an SVG G element
> d3.create("g") // an HTML G (unknown) element

So you need d3.create("svg:rect") in your code.